# Running bash scripts from bash script in other folder

Tags: bash, shell, script

I've got several folders (one for each month), each with a bash script `savetodatabase.sh`. I want to run all of them after each other, so I made a script named `saveall.sh` which has the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sh 2014/07-Jul/savetodatabase.sh
sh 2014/08-Aug/savetodatabase.sh
sh 2014/09-Sep/savetodatabase.sh
sh 2014/10-Oct/savetodatabase.sh
sh 2014/11-Nov/savetodatabase.sh
sh 2014/12-Dec/savetodatabase.sh
```

However, this runs the script in the folder saveall lies in, not the folders the different scripts lie in. How do I fix this, so that single script can run all of the "local" scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are in fact running the scripts from the directory you have saveall in. If you want to run each of the scripts in their folders (I assume you might have some output that is logging to the pwd?) then the easiest means would likely be to cd into each of the folders and then running the individual sh scripts. So something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd base_dir/2014/07-Jul
sh savetodatabase.sh
cd base_dir/2014/08-Aug
sh savetodatabase.sh
```

etc.

The reference to "base_dir" is to denote using the full path to your directories.

Alternatively, and depending entirely on the differences and complexity of your savetodatabase scripts, you may be able to combine the process in those scripts into a single script with some built in logic that allows for the variation based on the year/month. If it is just some variable changes you can have a txt 'config' file that the script reads and loops through (or some other such method to run through the variations) to get the different output.

All depends on which method to manage it works best for you :)

Answer (score 3):

This will run all executable files named `savetodatabase.sh` under the 2014 directory and its subdirectories, and each executable will be run within its directory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find 2014 -type f -executable -name savetodatabase.sh | while read script
do
  cd "$(dirname "$script")"
  sh "$(basename "$script")"
  cd -
done
```

This assumes, of course, that those files are marked as executable.